How the size of a parent inline element is determined?
I'm curious about how the size of a parent inline element is determined.
Actually, I read this docs1 and this docs2 before asking about this.
To be honest, I didn't understand it exactly.
It seems that the height of an inline element is determined by the linebox.
But please look at the following simple code.
<span>
   <img src="00f.jpg">
</span>

Here, the size of the image is 450x500. Therefore, the size of the img element is also 450x500.
And I expected the size of the span to be 450x500 as well.
Because the size of the linebox that wraps the img element inside the <span> is 450x500.
But the result is roughly 450x21.
Isn't the size of the parent inline element determined by the size of its child element?
What am I missing?

It's normal. <span> is an inline element, which does not contain the contents inside the tag. If you set the span tag with display: block, or change it to a block element like <p> or <div>, this parent element will have the size of its inner element (plus the padding / margin that user agent CSS defined, if any).

@Raptor Sorry for relying on ChatGPT, but Chatgpt said that the size of the parent span will be determined by the content size of the inline child element. I'm confused to be honest.

The width does, but not the height.
